# How to query Entities in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4, objectquery

In VS2008, I think it is EF1.0, this works just fine.

```
string queryString = @"SELECT VALUE USERS FROM ProjectDBEntities.Users AS User 
            INNER JOIN ProjectDBEntities.Favorites AS F ON F.FavUserId = User.UserId
            WHERE F.UserId = " + 3 + " ORDER BY F.CreateDate DESC ";

        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<User> usersQuery =
                new System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<User>(queryString, context).Include("Detail");

        //int count = usersQuery.Count();
        foreach (User result in usersQuery)
            Console.WriteLine("User Name: {0}", result.UserName);
```

Same code in VS2010 EF4 it crashes on the foreach loop with the following error:

**The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types.**

Comment: Do you require an ESQL solution? This would be trivial with L2E.

Comment: Craig, how would it done with L2E?

Comment: As per my post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/732cbb72-2ca0-45c3-8702-b30c3c077aa8/entitydatasource-issue?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required) it seems you don't need to specify the `Include` if you're already using a custom `Select`. (So try removing the Include).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from u in ProjectDBEntities.Users
        from f in u.Favorites
        where f.User.Id == 3
        orderby f.CreateDate desc;
```

I'm making some presumptions about your entity model/property names since you don't show it, but this should give you the general idea.